# Django, jquery and $.get

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, request

Is there a django function to detect if an ajax query was sent with `$.get`? Let me explain...

I use Ajax for 2 things:

1/ from my menu I display the content of each page with `$.get` (already implemented, it worked well until I started developing the second point)

2/ inside a form, when I click on a button, I use `$.ajax` to display a success or error message (currently being developed)

At the end of the first point, my view is unchanged. The last line:

```
return render_to_response('auth/index.html', response_dic, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However I had to change it for the second point:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    #transform the data to json so it can be used in jquery
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dic), mimetype='application/json')
#normal post with reload
else:
    return render_to_response('auth/index.html', response_dic, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But now nothing is displayed anymore when I click on a link of my menu! I think I know why: I call my view with `$.get`. In my view, `request.is_ajax()` returns `True` so it doesn't render the view as it should (it returns `HttpResponse` instead of `render_to_response`)!

So I repeat my question: is there a function to detect if ajax was used with a `GET`?
If it's not clear, ask me more details!
Here is my jQuery function:

```
//load the content of the page (right side) with Ajax (no need to reload the menu and header)
function load_content(link)
{
    $.get(link, function(data)
    {
        var title=$(data).find("#title");
        var content=$(data).find("#content");
        $("#title_base").html(title);
        $("#content_base").html(content);
    });

    //change the active link in the menu
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    //~ $(this).addClass("active");
    $('#menu a[href*="' + link.split("/")[2] + '"][class!="noselect"]').parent().addClass('active');
}
```

**Idea:** Should I use two different views?

Comment: `request.method == 'GET'`?

Comment: Right you are! The answer was simple! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**

### Solved!

**

I just had to use `request.GET`, as suggested mariodev. My view:

```
def login_view(request):

    logout(request)
    response_dic={}

    if request.POST:
        #page posted and processed with ajax
        ...
        #transform the data to json so it can be used in jquery
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_dic), mimetype='application/json')


    #displays the page (GET)
    return render_to_response('auth/index.html', response_dic, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) of the `$.get()` function: "This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to: `$.ajax(...)`". So there's really no difference.

If you want them to be treated differently, you'll have to create the difference yourself - either by calling different URLs (views) or by passing different parameters.

Comment: Ok it's what I thought in a first time. But even better and much simpler: I used `request.GET`.